# Diodes- circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

Hi! So I have this problem. I've read all the books I could and watched many youtube videos but I still cant understand how to find R in this circuit the only info I have is that V out=3. If someone could help me with this I would be soooo grateful! Thank you

Comment: remove D1, and compute the various voltages in the circuit. Then install D1, and determine the current thru D1. Be aware that diodes have an exponential current response to changes in voltage; 0.058 volts causes a 10:1 increase or 10:1 decrease, depending on the polarity 0.058 change.

Comment: You can not solve this problem without knowing what kind of diodes D1 and D2 are. Do you have a spec for these? BTW, which one is V out? I can only see V in the schematic.

Comment: No literally the profesor only gave us V and the graphic nothing else

Comment: If this is a class assignment, there is a very good chance that these are ideal diodes. But - you can calculate 3 or 4 different values of the resistor that correspond with the different diodes available. That is : ideal, Silicon, Schottky, Germanuim.

Answer (score 0):

If Vout (assuming it's V) is 3, then the voltage at node B will be 3 minus the diode drop (not sure what model is being used for the diodes, but assuming they're identical).  D1 will be reverse biased and I will be small and negative (or zero if using an ideal model).  Just as an approximation, I'll assume each diode has a 0.7V drop and is otherwise ideal...

I will be zero; Vout is 3; Vb is 2.3, so there's 12.3V across the 10K resistor.  Calculate the current and figure out what resistance would result in a 7V drop.